# How can I output certain data continuously in the CMD and user input at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, output, python-multithreading

I need to be able to output certain data continuously in the CMD and receive user input at the same time. Can anyone help me? I searched for a long time but found nothing...

Example:

```
00:04:20    <-- data
Password:   <-- input
```

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is the real problem? The request doesn't make much sense as continuous output while user inputs, will only confuse the user.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.